# ¿Como obtener datos anidados filtrados con XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

estoy haciendo un ejercicio sobre XSLT, para el cual hice un XML en su momento, con una serie de consultas en xpath y xquery, y ahora tengo que basarme en una de esas consultas para aplicar una transformación con xslt.
En concreto, la transformación que deseo aplicar a mi xml es un filtrado por género de lucha (el xml es una base de datos sobre videojuegos).

El XML en concreto es este, y en mi transformación xslt quiero que me de un output con las plataformas (name), el título del juego (title) y el género (genre=lucha).
¿Podéis explicarme cómo consigo hacerlo?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<systems>
   <name type="arcade">
      Sega Naomi
      <release_date>1998</release_date>
      <gamelist>
         <title>
            Dead or Alive 2
            <bios>JAP</bios>
            <release>1999</release>
            <genre>lucha</genre>
            <dif>easy</dif>
         </title>
         <title>
            Crazy Taxi
            <bios>EUR</bios>
            <release>1999</release>
            <genre>conduccion</genre>
            <dif>medium</dif>
         </title>
         <title>
            House of the dead 2
            <bios>USA</bios>
            <release>1999</release>
            <genre>disparos</genre>
            <dif>medium</dif>
         </title>
      </gamelist>
   </name>
   <name type="arcade">
      Sammy Atomiswave
      <release_date>2001</release_date>
      <gamelist>
         <title>
            Dolphin Blue
            <bios>JAP</bios>
            <release>2000</release>
            <genre>plataformas</genre>
            <dif>easy</dif>
         </title>
         <title>
            Samurai Shodown 6
            <bios>JAP</bios>
            <release>2005</release>
            <genre>lucha</genre>
            <dif>hard</dif>
         </title>
         <title>
            The king of fighters 11
            <bios>JAP</bios>
            <release>2005</release>
            <genre>lucha</genre>
            <dif>hard</dif>
         </title>
      </gamelist>
   </name>
   <name type="arcade">
      Sega Model
      <release_date>1992</release_date>
      <gamelist>
         <title>
            Virtua fighter
            <bios>USA</bios>
            <release>1992</release>
            <genre>lucha</genre>
            <dif>easy</dif>
         </title>
         <title>
            Star wars arcade
            <bios>USA</bios>
            <release>1994</release>
            <genre>conduccion</genre>
            <dif>hard</dif>
         </title>
         <title>
            Virtua formula
            <bios>EUR</bios>
            <release>1993</release>
            <genre>conducion</genre>
            <dif>hard</dif>
         </title>
      </gamelist>
   </name>
   <name type="consola">
      Sega Dreamcast
      <release_date>1999</release_date>
      <bios>USA, EUR, JAP</bios>
      <gamelist>
         <title>
            Shenmue
            <release>1999</release>
            <genre>accion</genre>
            <dif>medium</dif>
         </title>
         <title>
            Shenmue 2
            <release>2001</release>
            <genre>accion</genre>
            <dif>medium</dif>
         </title>
         <title>
            Resident evil 3
            <release>1999</release>
            <genre>terror</genre>
            <dif>hard</dif>
         </title>
         <title>
            Power stone
            <release>1999</release>
            <genre>lucha</genre>
            <dif>medium</dif>
         </title>
      </gamelist>
   </name>
   <name type="consola">
      Sega Megadrive
      <release_date>1988</release_date>
      <gamelist>
         <title>
            Sonic
            <release>1991</release>
            <genre>plataformas</genre>
            <dif>medium</dif>
         </title>
         <title>
            Sonic 2
            <release>1992</release>
            <genre>plataformas</genre>
            <dif>medium</dif>
         </title>
         <title>
            Sonic 3
            <release>1994</release>
            <genre>plataformas</genre>
            <dif>medium</dif>
         </title>
         <title>
            Street fighter 2
            <release>1991</release>
            <genre>lucha</genre>
            <dif>medium</dif>
         </title>
         <title>
            Rocket knight
            <release>1993</release>
            <genre>plataformas</genre>
            <dif>medium</dif>
         </title>
      </gamelist>
   </name>
</systems>
```

Comment: Hola, Para formatear el codigo puedes usar las herramientas que están disponibles en el editor. Hay un botón ´{}´ que sirve para formatear el texto como codigo, tambien pueden agregar una sangria de 4 espacios para convertirlo manualmente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `xsl:for-each` y `select="path[field='term']"` para filtrar, tambien puedes usar `child::text()` para obtener el texto dentro de las etiquetas.

Este XSLT debería poder consultar los datos que necesitas:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>Videogames</h2>
            <table border="1">
               <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                  <th>Platform</th>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Genre</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="systems">
                  <xsl:for-each select="name/gamelist/title[genre='lucha']">
                     <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="../../child::text()" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="child::text()" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="genre" /></td>
                     </tr>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

En el sitio de [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp) hay mas informacion sobre esto.

Saludos

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ahora mismo estaba mirando el W3Schools, estoy cotejando el código que me has pasado para tratar de entenderlo bien.

Saludos!